# Firebase emulator, set test phone sms code

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

When trying to authenticate with a phone against firebase auth emulator, the emulator output those kinds of messages:

```
To verify the phone number +16505551234, use the code 376579.
```

I would like to know if there is a way to set that code to be something static so I can run some integrations tests.

Just to be clear I already added a test phone to firebase (not the emulator) with it's code, but the emulator does not pick it up. The emulator ui interface does not seem to have the option to add one either.

It just generates a new code for every authentication and I want to put a static one for example "123456"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to set a static verification code as per the source here :

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/7271c958eea82b8d223c0e581a94e3b5b7e57619/src/emulator/auth/state.ts

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#create-fictional-phone-numbers-and-verification-codes) covers adding phone numbers for testing.

> **Create fictional phone numbers and verification codes**
>
> 1. In the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), open the **Authentication** section.
> 2. In the **Sign in method** tab, enable the Phone provider if you haven't already.
> 3. Open the **Phone numbers for testing** accordion menu.
> 4. Provide the phone number you want to test, for example: *+1 650-555-3434.*
> 5. Provide the 6-digit verification code for that specific number, for example: *654321*.
> 6. **Add** the number. If there's a need, you can delete the phone number and its code by hovering over the corresponding row and clicking the trash icon.

Importantly, the test numbers you use should not exist! Especially, don't use your own phone number for these tests!

Further down in the documentation, you will find more details regarding integration testing.

Comment: I did that already, but it does not work with the emulator, which is what this question is about. I added that information to the question to clear the confusion

Comment: @Ced Ah, I was under the impression that the emulator respected these test numbers.